# Building an HTML document with content from another

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm have a document **A** and want to build a new one **B** using **A**'s node values.

Given **A** looks like this...

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="section0">
      <h1>Section 0</h1>
      <div>
        <p>Some <b>important</b> info here</p>
        <div>Some unimportant info here</p>
      </div>
    <div>
    <div id="section1">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <div>
        <p>Some <i>important</i> info here</p>
        <div>Some unimportant info here</div>
      </div>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When building a **B** document, I'm using method `a.at_css("#section#{n} h1").text` to grab the data from **A**'s `h1` tags like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

a = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
  ...
  doc.h1 a.at_css("#section#{n} h1").text
  ...
end
```

So there are three questions:

1. How do I grab the content of `<p>` tags preserving tags inside
   `<p>`?

   Currently, once I hit `a.at_css("#section#{n} p").text` it
   returns a plain text, which is not what's needed.

   If, instead of `.text` I hit `.to_html` or `.inner_html`, the html appears escaped. So I get, for example, `&lt;p&gt;` instead of `<p>`.
2. Is there any known *true* way of assigning nodes at the document building stage? So that I wouldn't dance with `text` method at all? I.e. how do I assign `doc.h1` node with value of `a.at_css("#section#{n} h1")` node at building stage?
3. What's the profit of `Nokogiri::Builder.with(...)` method? I wonder if I can get use of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **How do I grab the content of `<p>` tags preserving tags inside `<p>`?**

   Use `.inner_html`. The entities are not escaped when accessing them. They *will* be escaped if you do something like `builder.node_name raw_html`. Instead:

   ```ruby
   require 'nokogiri'
   para = Nokogiri.HTML( '<p id="foo">Hello <b>World</b>!</p>' ).at('#foo')

   doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |d|
     d.body do
       d.div(id:'content') do
         d.parent << para.inner_html
       end
     end
   end

   puts doc.to_html
   #=> <body><div id="content">Hello <b>World</b>!</div></body>
   ```
2. **Is there any known true way of assigning nodes at the document building stage?**

   Similar to the above, one way is:

   ```ruby
   puts Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new{ |d| d.body{ d.parent << para } }.to_html
   #=> <body><p id="foo">Hello <b>World</b>!</p></body>
   ```

   Voila! The node has moved from one document to the other.
3. **What's the profit of `Nokogiri::Builder.with(...)` method?**

   That's rather unrelated to the rest of your question. As [the documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-c-with) says:

   > *Create a builder with an existing root object. This is for use when you have an existing document that you would like to augment with builder methods. The builder context created will start with the given `root` node.*

   I don't think it would be useful to you here.

In general, I find the Builder to be convenient when writing a large number of custom nodes from scratch with a known hierarchy. When not doing that you may find it simpler to just create a new document and use DOM methods to add nodes as appropriate. It's hard to tell how much hard-coded nodes/hierarchy your document will have versus procedurally created.

One other, alternative suggestion: perhaps you should create a template XML document and then augment that with details from the other, scraped HTML?

Comment: As to your question: I've done the template approach as you described, but still wanted to figure out if there's a more true way of doing that.